# Wordpress - Get posts by comparing ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve the posts in **Wordpress** that have `post_id < $number` , so I looked for it in the documentation, and tried this code :

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'       => 10,
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'offset'            => 0,
    'orderby'           => 'id',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    array(
        'key'     => 'post_id',
        'value'   => '3000',
        'compare' => '<'
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->get_posts();
```

but it didn't work (return the last 10 posts without comparing the ID), and I couldn't find an answer :(

So, could tell me please how to do it ..

And thanks in advance ..

Comment: Please define "didn't work" in this case. What is the output? Also note that you are limiting your query to 10 posts.

Comment: @JArkinstall I mean that it returned the last posts without comparing the ID,
And I limited it to 10 posts because I wanted it to return just 10 posts (as example)

Comment: I dont think you can use sub-query for post id, only 'post__in' and 'post__not_in' parameters are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query. it will return you array with your desired data.

```
   global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID < 10;" );
```